# How do I detach hover event on pseudo element from _parent_

Tags: html, css

I have a `<span/>` element and pseudo element `::before`, *attached* to that.

My problem is that cursor `hover` on `::before` pseudo element triggers `hover` on `<span/>` (so `text-decoration: underline` of a `<span/>` takes effect).

How do I make (using CSS) `::before` trigger no event on `hover`, so that when I place cursor over pseudo element no `hover` `text-decoration` is triggered on `<span/>`?

I tried `pointer-events: none` at no avail.

```css
#example {
  color: purple;
}

#example:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#example::before {
  color: orange;
  content: "<I am ::before>";
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<span id="example">I am sample text</span>
```

Comment: Basically you can't...if you are hovering the psuedo-element you are hovering the parent.

Comment: @Paulie_D https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mou3qxyt/. But this feels a little hacky since you need to explicitly set the width/margin/translate etc

Comment: @j08691: if I got the idea, you placed `::before` and `<span />` at the _same spot_ than tricked the former with `transform` to move left (to area where `hover` is triggered). Is that correct? You may post your solution as the answer and I'll accept that.

Comment: @Curr195 Yes, essentially. Realize though that this inly works with the set positioning and doesn't work if the content of `:before` will change

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but why can't you just remove `text-decoration: underline;` or set it to `none`?

Comment: @AuthenticScience: I still need it to decorate `<span/>` text on `hover`

Comment: I'm dumb (⊙.☉)7